# Expose boost::multi_array<std::string, 1> to python

Tags: python, c++, c++11, numpy, boost

I tried to expose a `boost::multi_array<std::string, 1>` as numpy array, but I get

```
ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize
```

if I try to access it in Python. I use the following template to create a Python object:

```
template<typename TMultiArray, typename TData>
bp::object getNumpyArray(boost::shared_ptr<TMultiArray> array, int dimensions, int npy_type) {
    TData* data = (*array).data();
    npy_intp* shape = (npy_intp*) (*array).shape();
    PyObject* pyObj = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(dimensions, shape, npy_type, data);
    boost::python::object arr(boost::python::handle<>(boost::python::borrowed(pyObj)));
    return arr;
}
```

Calling with:

```
getNumpyArray<boost::multi_array<std::string, 1>, std::string>(array, 1, NPY_STRING);
```

I'm using numpy 1.7.1.

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Why are you using a Numpy array to store strings? It may be that Numpy can't do your "access" on an array of strings, rather than any issue with Boost.

Comment: @leewangzhong its part of a larger project, so I currently use a wrapper class for storing int/float and strings. Internally I use a  multi_array. The main use case is for numeric calculations, so I used numpy on the python side. I thought it would also provide some automatic conversion if strings are used, but as I now understand numpy uses a different memory model for strings, so this cannot be done. I think I will now use a different approach to use array of strings.